# Continuous real-valued functions defined on non-compact spaces

Tags: general-topology

A continuous real-valued function defined on a compact space is bounded and attains its bounds. Is it so that on a non-compact space it is always possible to define a continuous function that does not have these properties? (In fact, this is the case if the non-compact set lies in a finite-dimensional normed vector space, because in this case the set is either not closed or not bounded.)

Comment: Perhaps look at [this previous answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/349073/8348) of mine.

Answer (score 2):

No. A space with your property is called [pseudocompact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocompact_space). A pseudocompact space need not be compact: for example, an infinite set with the [particular point topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology).

Comment: $X$ is pseudocompact if image of any continuous function $f \colon X \to \mathbb R$ is bounded. But nothing is said about attainability of its bounds. So author of question speaks about some subclass of pseudocompact spaces, right? Is there a name for such subclass?

Comment: @Nimza: It's easy to see that this subclass is in fact, as I stated in my answer, the whole thing.

Comment: Ah, yes, if $f^\ast$ for example is upper not-atteinable bound of $f$, then $x \mapsto 1/(f^\ast-f(x))$ will be unbounded

Comment: What can we say if the compact set is a subset of an infinite- dimensional normed vector space or, more generally, is a metric space?

Comment: @RodneyColeman: We can say lots of things about such sets. Do you have an actual question about them?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not: there are $T_3$ spaces on which every real-valued continuous function is constant.  E.  K.  van  Douwen,  *A  regular  space  on  which  every  continuous  real-valued  function  is  constant*,  Nieuw
Arch. Wisk.  20  (1972),  143-145, is a particularly nice example.