# How to show that $\exists~f\in C(X,\mathbb R)$ such that $f$ is unbounded?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a non-compact metric space. How to show that $\exists~f\in C(X,\mathbb R)$ such that $f$ is unbounded?

Comment: if you don't know where to start, thinking about the contradiction may help you see thru some ideas.  What is the negation of the conclusion?

Comment: The answer is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114123/if-every-continuous-function-attains-its-maximum-then-the-metric-space-is-comp/114127#114127).