# Assume that the metric space $(X, d)$ is not compact then there exist a $f: X \to \Bbb R$ which is continuous but not bounded.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Assume that the metric space $(X, d)$ is not compact then there exist a $f: X \to \Bbb R$ which is continuous but not bounded.

I am finding difficulty in constructing such a function!!

Comment: See the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114123/if-every-continuous-function-attains-its-maximum-then-the-metric-space-is-comp).

Comment: other examples can be interesting to see.