# Proving $X$ is totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

> Show that if any continuous real-valued function on a metric space $X$ attains
> its maximum value, then $X$ is totally bounded.

So, want to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a finite subset $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ of $X$ s.t. $X\subset\cup_{k=1}^nB(x_k,\epsilon)$.

I'm thinking to prove it using contrapositive, that if $X$ is not totally bounded then there exists a continuous real valued function on $X$ that is unbounded above, but I'm stuck!!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wait what? $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ is a continuous function that attains a maximum at $x=0$ but there is no way that $\mathbb{R}$ is contained inside of finitely many epsilon balls for any $\varepsilon>0$

Comment: @CSquared We need every continuous function to attain a maximum so $f(x)=x$ wouldn't attain a maximum.

Comment: @daruma i assume for clarity then, it should read ‘if $\texit{every}$ continuous real-valued...’

Comment: @ArcticChar Specifically : the second case in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114338) answer is a solution to the OP